# npm ERR! Missing script, but the script is there when I run "npm run"?

Tags: json, batch-file, cmd, npm-scripts

I am trying to run a .bat file that simply echoes 'hello', to learn more about package.json and scripts. I have this:

```
"scripts": {
   "buildSwaggerFiles": "buildSwaggerFiles",
 },
```

but when I run `npm run buildSwaggerFiles`, I recieve the error that I either misspelled the command, or it doesn't exist (It's in german otherwise I'd just paste the error here). The same error pops up if I add `.bat`:

```
"scripts": {
   "buildSwaggerFiles": "buildSwaggerFiles.bat",
 },
```

So I thought I needed to add the path, even though I haven't seen that online anywhere? It then looked like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "buildSwaggerFiles": "projects/common/src/lib/buildSwaggerFiles.bat",
 },
```

Same error, so I added `npm run`:

```
"scripts": {
   "buildSwaggerFiles": "npm run projects/common/src/lib/buildSwaggerFiles.bat",
 },
```

And then I get the error `npm ERR! Missing script: "projects/common/src/lib/buildSwaggerFiles.bat"`, however when I run `npm run`, it shows me this:

```
Scripts available in angular-library@0.0.0 via npm run-script:
buildSwaggerFiles
    projects/common/src/lib/buildSwaggerFiles.bat
```

At this point I am lost. Am I in the wrong Terminal? The terminal destination is Angular-Library, which contains the mentioned 'projects' folder, as well as the package.json. To clarify, the package.json is in the same folder as the projects folder that contains the script I am trying to run. Is that my problem? Can I not run .bat files through package.json? What else can I try? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who may find this useful:
I managed to solve it by putting `node` before listing the path to my script file, like so:`"buildSwaggerFiles": "node projects/common/src/lib/buildSwaggerFiles.bat",`